# Can Nginx(webserver) replaced with fortigate WAF?

Tags: nginx, fortigate

We are going to replace nginx nodes with fortigate waf. Would WAF have all features sets which nginx having

1. Rewrite rules
2. IPv6
3. SSL
4. Load balancing on the bases of subdomain/context
5. compression and caching
6. other

Please suggest if I missed to figure out options in nginx which are not supporting in fortigate web application firewall

Comment: A WAF is not a web server.

Comment: I know however mentioned features are supported by WAF also. Can you please give better reason.